# Visually hide last span inside of a class

Tags: javascript, css, antd

I am utilizing ANTD checkbox group and the designs I am working with do not show the label next to the checkbox. I have temporarily added a solution that uses JavaScript to dynmaically add a class to the last child node. But I can't seem to figure out a way to hide the nested span inside of a label without JavaScript. I tried using last-of-type, last-child, nth-child etc... but apparently I suck at targeting the last span of a class. Any advice and or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**ANTD's produced code - the span highlighted is what I am trying to visually hide:**

[image]

Comment: `label.ant-checkbox > span:last-child { display: none }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out in the comments, you want to use `:last-child`. However, his code uses the wrong class name. Here's a full demo of what you can do:

```css
label.ant-checkbox-wrapper > span:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
<label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
</label>
```